# Generate maps from different columns of shapefile with QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, software-recommendations, visualisation

I have a shapefile with N columns describing different attributes of some features. I would like to generate a grid of maps, where each map is a different column. Visually, I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

I can easily generate a single map manually with QGIS, but I would like to automate the process to be able to generate hundreds of such maps very quickly.

I started to code a **PyQGIS** script following [this recipe](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html), but I keep getting segmentation faults (I'm on MacOS X, QGIS Wien).

What would you recommend? I thought of using R, but the output tends to be visually less appealing than QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab-)use the TimeManager plugin for this by making it output each frame of its animation as image. If your data has no time values, just fake them by incrementing an integer.